# getting mypy's to handle getters and setters in dataclasses

Tags: python, mypy

I have a dataclass like

```
@dataclass
class Passport:
    byr: int

    @property
    def byr(self) -> int:
        return self._byr

    @byr.setter
    def byr(self, value) -> None:
        if int(value) < 1920 or int(value) > 2002:
            raise Exception("Birth year must be between 1920 and 2002")
        self._byr = int(value)
```

This code runs correctly, but mypy gives the error `error: Name 'byr' already defined on line 10`. I can change my initialisation to say `_byr: int` but this changes my codes behaviour, making it fail my unit tests. Specifically, I can no longer write something like `Passport(byr=2000)`, which is required for me.

Any ideas how to solve this? Or is mypy just not designed yet to handle getters and setters in dataclasses?

Comment: I would say that *dataclasses* are not designed to handle this. The point of a ``dataclass`` is creating a simple, record-like container. Having a separate interface and hidden, verified storage goes beyond the goals of a ``dataclass``. A custom class or more powerful third party library such as ``attrs`` might be more suitable.

Comment: thats fair enough, I can see that. I think I'll switch over to it not being a dataclass then. thank you